# Moving heavy data

Tags: windows, data-transfer

I mistakenly downloaded some big archives from a one time download website on a computer where I can't take admin rights or use network share from Explorer

I need to move out those archives from the computer. Are there any software? (I would prefer without the need of buying an expensive and big portable storage, not-SneakerNet approach, so preferably free solution)

Comment: How would you install this software without admin rights? I think it's time for a sneakernet approach, carry a drive from one to the other.

Comment: If a pendrive/portable hard disk is out of question then the only possible solution is to upload the data somewhere on internet and download from the other side. If you're on the same network, a local file share/FTP or similar would do. You don't need any software for any of that.

Comment: I'm on the same network. It's fine for me to use a share/FTP or whatever else as long as you explain to me what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/), provided you can grant it access to the internet.

It is a file and folder synchronization software that works on multiple platforms (Windows, Mac, Linux and Android) and can sync files and entire folder hierarchies over a network connection.

It can use both local networks or over the internet, and sync individual folders between multiple devices, using unique device IDs.

It doesn't need to be formally installed, it is available as a "portable" zipped setup which requires only unpacking to a folder of choice and running the executable.

As far as I'm aware it requires no admin rights, may will almost certainly trigger a firewall notification requesting access to the network. Depending on how locked down the system is it may work for you.

Comment: The transfer between computers works fine. Though, I would have preferred a local transfer. Here it's not clear if it's local. Because computers are announced with their local IP + Relay IP. And because data seems to be sent to meet.lazawan.net instead of the computer local IP (though there is a liiiitle bit of traffic between both computers local IP). Through it's fine because I think that the 1st computer NIC bandwidth seems to be saturated, so it couldn't have been done better. I'm just worrying about my personal data transiting through WAN

Comment: Can't say much about the technical workings, according to documentation if computers are behind a NAT it uses [Relay](https://docs.syncthing.net/specs/relay-v1.html) things may be piped through the internet, but as far as I know are not stored elsewhere permanently

Comment: meet.lazawan.net seems to be some sort of chat, conference or video call service

Comment: My local network is behind a NAT but both computers are on this nated network, so they can communicate through local IP, and they do (not with Syncthing). Data are not announced to be stored permanently, but just by common sense, it's more secure to just stay on LAN. On port 80 yeah

Comment: In my experience, for two computers in LAN, Syncthing moves stuffs directly in the LAN.

Comment: I didn't liked that my files were moving through WAN. I think my computer is so locked up that it needs to use a peer who have a valid SSL certificate, hence any website on internet but not my local computer. But yeah it did the job through WAN, so it's the solution. But I advise strongly people to use a LAN only solution. Maybe tinker to forbid WAN transfer or use a software where we can control where data transit

Answer (score 1):

Syncthing is a good solution, as mentioned by Duarte Farrajota Ramos above. But if you only intend to do this once between the two computers, probably there is no need to bother setting up that.

You did not specify if the two machines are on the same network (LAN) or not. So I'll suggest based on the difference scenarios.

### On the same network (LAN)

You could use other LAN file-sharing applications or protocols. There are tons of them. In particular, consider using [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) first.

FTP was the standard protocol for file-serving. You only need to get an application on machine A (with that file) to start the FTP server. Then visit that server on machine B (where you want the file).
Most web browsers support FTP protocol, so you probably don't need any additional software on B. But if you really want, FileZilla is a good choice (it's open-source).

Note the transmission is not secured, though probably this is not a concern for your use case.

### Not on the same network (LAN)

There is [Magic Wormhole](https://github.com/magic-wormhole/magic-wormhole) which is meant for people to share data/file from one computer to another over the Internet **without** storing the file somewhere first. You don't need to pair two devices -- simply use the same passphrase.

I only used it on Linux. It's pretty straightforward: simply choose the file you want to send, and you'll be given a passphrase (several words); then, on the receiver side, type that passphrase and it will be transmitted.
I did all that over commandline. Probably there are GUI clients as well.

Similar to Syncthing, it automatically relays between two machines behind (different) firewalls. I'm not sure if it does whole-punching or not.